# how to set gallery image into different frames in android

Tags: android-framework

I am making a small project photo frames, in which i am trying to set a gallery image on frame but the problem is the frames are in different forms. So may i know how may i adjust the image in these different frames.

I done code for take image from gallery. I done code for gridview  list of frames. But the problem is when i click on the gridview item, frame displayed in another activity. But how can i set gallery image into these frames. please send your ideas and rectify my mistake in coding 
The problem occur in the MultiTouch activity. Plz rectify my error in coding.

the code i am using in main activity

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1)
        {
            Image_Picker_Dialog();
        }

}


    public void Image_Picker_Dialog()
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pictures Option");
        builder.setMessage("Select Picture Mode");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                    {

                        Utility.pictureActionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                        Utility.pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
                        Utility.pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        startActivityForResult(Utility.pictureActionIntent, Utility.GALLERY_PICTURE);
                    }
            });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                    {
                        Utility.pictureActionIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(Utility.pictureActionIntent, Utility.CAMERA_PICTURE);
                    }
            });
        builder.show();

    }


    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if (requestCode == Utility.GALLERY_PICTURE)
        {

            // data contains result 
            // Do some task 
            b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            b2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            b3.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            Image_Selecting_Task(data);
            selectframe(b2);

            } else if (requestCode == Utility.CAMERA_PICTURE)
        {
            // Do some task
             Image_Selecting_Task(data);
             selectframe(b2);

        }



}





    public void Image_Selecting_Task(Intent data){
        try
        {
            Utility.uri = data.getData();
            if (Utility.uri != null)
                {
                    // User had pick an image.
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Utility.uri, new String[]
                        { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    // Link to the image
                    final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);

                    //Assign string path to File
                    Utility.Default_DIR = new File(imageFilePath);

                    // Create new dir MY_IMAGES_DIR if not created and copy image into that dir and store that image path in valid_photo
                    Utility.Create_MY_IMAGES_DIR();

                    // Copy your image 
                    Utility.copyFile(Utility.Default_DIR, Utility.MY_IMG_DIR);

                    // Get new image path and decode it

                    Bitmap b = Utility.decodeFile(Utility.Paste_Target_Location);

                    // use new copied path and use anywhere 
                    String valid_photo = Utility.Paste_Target_Location.toString();
                    b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,150,150, true);

                    //set your selected image in image view

                    iv.setImageBitmap(b);
                    cursor.close();

                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(this,Fullpicture.class);
                    intent.putExtra("bmp",b);
                    startActivity(intent);*/

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream);
                    byte[] byteArray = bStream.toByteArray();

                    Intent i = new Intent(this,MultiTouch.class);
                    i.putExtra("image", byteArray);
                    startActivity(i);





                } else
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't selecet any image.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // you get this when you will not select any single image 
            Log.e("onActivityResult", "" + e);

        }
    }


    public void selectframe(View v){ 

            Intent i=new Intent();

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),Selectframes.class));

            startActivity(i); 



    }

    public void addListenerOnButton3() {

                    //Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
                   Button b3  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

                    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                          Intent openBrowser =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=schoolinmobile&c=apps&hl=en"));
                          startActivity(openBrowser);
                        }

                    });

                }
    public void addListenerOnButton2() {

        //Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
       Button b2  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i=new Intent();

                i.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),Selectframes.class));
                startActivity(i); 


            }

        });

    }
```

Main.Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/photo6"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.photoframes.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#00FFFF"
            android:onClick="TAKE PHOTO"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="TAKE PHOTO" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#00FFFF"
            android:onClick="MORE APPS"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="MORE APPS" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#00FFFF"
            android:onClick="SELECT FRAME"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="SELECT FRAME" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SelectFrame Activity:

```
public class Selectframes extends Activity {
 Bitmap b;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectframes);



        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new ImageAdapter(this));

         // On Click event for Single Gridview Item

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent newintent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MultiTouch.class);
                // passing array index
                newintent.putExtra("id", position);

                startActivity(newintent);


            }
        });


    }

}
```

selectframe.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/photo7"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="454dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.78"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="40dp" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MultiTouch Activity:

```
public class MultiTouch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
ImageView view;
ImageView iv;
Bitmap b;
Button b1;
Bitmap mBitmap;


    // these matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    // we can be in one of these 3 states
    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int DRAG = 1;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;
    private int mode = NONE;
    // remember some things for zooming
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    private float oldDist = 1f;
    private float d = 0f;
    private float newRot = 0f;
    private float[] lastEvent = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.touch);

        ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        iv.setImageBitmap(b);

        iv.setOnTouchListener(this);



        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        view.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);     


        Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

         }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // handle touch events here
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 3) {
                        newRot = rotation(event);
                        float r = newRot - d;
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        float tx = values[2];
                        float ty = values[5];
                        float sx = values[0];
                        float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                        float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                        matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the degree to be rotated by.
     *
     * @param event
     * @return Degrees
     */
    private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);

    }
    public void addListenerOnButton1() {

        //Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
       Button b1  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                        Drawable image = iv.getDrawable();
                        if(image != null && image instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image;
                            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                            try {
                                File file = new File("Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values");
                                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                stream.flush();
                                stream.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                        }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Multitoch.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:scaleType="matrix" 

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     </LinearLayout>
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="save"
        android:text="save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you

```
   in logcat :



12-13 11:13:30.617: W/dalvikvm(21598): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a8ce0)
12-13 11:13:30.617: W/dalvikvm(21598): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
12-13 11:13:30.617: W/System.err(21598): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.photoframes/com.example.photoframes.MultiTouch}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 11:13:30.618: W/System.err(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
12-13 11:13:30.618: W/System.err(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
12-13 11:13:30.618: W/System.err(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
12-13 11:13:30.618: W/System.err(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
12-13 11:13:30.618: W/System.err(21598):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
12-13 11:13:30.618: W/System.err(21598):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-13 11:13:30.618: W/System.err(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
12-13 11:13:30.618: W/System.err(21598):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 11:13:30.619: W/System.err(21598):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-13 11:13:30.619: W/System.err(21598):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
12-13 11:13:30.619: W/System.err(21598):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
12-13 11:13:30.619: W/System.err(21598):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 11:13:30.619: W/System.err(21598): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 11:13:30.620: W/System.err(21598):    at com.example.photoframes.MultiTouch.onCreate(MultiTouch.java:64)
12-13 11:13:30.620: W/System.err(21598):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5286)
12-13 11:13:30.620: W/System.err(21598):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
12-13 11:13:30.621: W/System.err(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
12-13 11:13:30.621: W/System.err(21598):    ... 11 more
12-13 11:13:30.621: W/dalvikvm(21598): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598): Process: com.example.photoframes, PID: 21598
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.photoframes/com.example.photoframes.MultiTouch}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at com.example.photoframes.MultiTouch.onCreate(MultiTouch.java:64)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5286)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
12-13 11:13:30.625: E/AndroidRuntime(21598):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: you must try Gallery View ... there are 3 thinks user Gallery View gallery slider and Image view /....../ 
try using a gallery view to show the images .....

Comment: sir the problem occur when i send gallery image into multitouch activity the project unfortunatly stoped.

Comment: put the code in try catch , there might be a null pointer exception in the code , read the crash code in the Logcat and paste it here so that i  would be easy that why app crashes

Comment: I posted logcat details.when i select fame error will occur

Comment: I did add try catch block,the frame is displayed but gallery image is not displayed in multitouch.xml